# Notice period calculation as an employee in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, contracts

As an employee I have a notice period of one week. If I hand in my notice on Wednesday, will my last day at work be the next Wednesday? Or the next Tuesday?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the workplace stack exchange site. But is very likely a duplicate on that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hand in your notice on Wednesday, your notice period is generally considered to begin the day after you handed in your notice, so your final working day would be the following Wednesday.

However, you should generally hand in your notice in the form of a letter stating your notice period and your expected last day, so they can query / clarify if needed.